# Datatables when checked rows this should be selected and others same group_id product should be disable

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js, datatables

My code has two steps:

**Step 1: I select data from datatable.**

**Step 2: If data with same group_id gets selected there should be given an error.**

But it did not work, please help me.  Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#productTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).hasClass('selected'));
      });
    });
                    
goCustomerStep() {
  var table= $('#productTable').DataTable();
  // Valid Table
  var arr = [];
  $.each(table.rows('.selected').data(), function(i, row) {
    console.log(table.rows('.selected').data());
    console.log("ok",row['group_id']);
    for(var z=0; z<arr.length; z++) {
      console.log(arr[z]);
      if (arr[z]['group_id'] === 1) {
        console.log('test');
      } else {
        arr.push(row);
      }
    }
  });

  if (arr.length > 0) {
    this.selectedProducts = arr;
    this.wizard.goTo(3);
  } else {
    swal.fire({
      title: 'Warning',
      text: 'Please choose product',
      type: 'warning',
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: There is not a lot we can help you with with this explanation. We don't know what or how much data is in your table. Please provide us with a reproducable example.

Comment: Back L0648 passive
 Back L0650 passive
 Back L0651 passive
 Right Shoulder L3960RT passive
 Left Shoulder L3960LT passive
 Right Knee L1833RT passive
 Left Knee L1833LT passive
 Right Knee L1851RT passive
 Left Knee L1851LT passive
 Right Ankle L1971RT passive
 Left Ankle L1971LT passive
 Right Ankle L1906RT passive
 Left Ankle L1906LT passive
 Right Wrist L3916RT passive
 Left Wrist L3916LT passive
 CGM Reader K0554 passive
 CGM Sensors K0553 passive

Comment: my data is. I want to in data for example i have 3 Back kod as you can see it. if i checked ones other two should be disable or it should not be selected. @Roboroads